# How to make the cells longer so the text would fill multiple lines instead

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table} [H]
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1.1\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    ~ & \textbf{Kriegers flak} & \textbf{Horns rev 3} \\ \hline
    Starttidspunkt & Forventet idriftsættelse 31. december 2018 & Forventet idriftsættelse 1. januar 2020 \\ \hline
    Kapacitet  &  590 MW – 610 MW afhængig af hvilken type mølle der bliver valgt &  406.7 MW \\ \hline
    Antal møller &  60-200 afhænger af hvilke møller de vælger at opsætte & 49 \\ \hline Turbinemodel & Endnu ikke valgt & Vestas V164-8.0MW \\ \hline
    Effekt pr. mølle (MW) & 3-10 & 8.3 \\ \hline
    Ejer  & Udbudsat af Energistyrelsen  & Vattenfall \\ \hline
    Rotordiameter (m) & Afhænger af den turbine de vælger & 164  \\ \hline
    Fundament  & Forventet monopæle & Monopæle \\ \hline
    Levetid (år) & 30 & 25 \\ \hline
    Areal (km$^2$) & 183 & 88 (Hele projekt arealet er på omkring 140) \\ \hline
    Forventet elpris (øre/kWh) & 80-90 & 77 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most basic approach is use the `p{<lenght>}` columns, but here is mixed with the `L` columns of the `tabulary` enviroment, so you can control also the total width easily. As usual, the example is done without vertical rules and with `booktabs` rules:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabulary,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedright}p{3cm}LL}\toprule
~ & \textbf{Kriegers flak} & \textbf{Horns rev 3} \\\midrule
Starttidspunkt & Forventet idriftsættelse 31. december 2018 & Forventet idriftsættelse 1. januar 2020 \\
Kapacitet  &  590 MW – 610 MW afhængig af hvilken type mølle der bliver valgt &  406.7 MW \\
Antal møller &  60-200 afhænger af hvilke møller de vælger at opsætte & 49 \\
Turbinemodel & Endnu ikke valgt & Vestas V164-8.0MW \\
Effekt pr. mølle (MW) & 3-10 & 8.3 \\
Ejer  & Udbudsat af Energistyrelsen  & Vattenfall \\
Rotordiameter (m) & Afhænger af den turbine de vælger & 164  \\ 
Fundament  & Forventet monopæle & Monopæle \\
Levetid (år) & 30 & 25 \\
Areal (km$^2$) & 183 & 88 (Hele projekt arealet er på omkring 140) \\
Forventet elpris (øre/kWh) & 80-90 & 77 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So if i wanted to keep all the horizontal and vertical lines, what should i change? I tried some, but i can't make the lines connect

Comment: @MathiasAndersen. Really, do not use vertical lines nor unnecessary horizontal lines. I suggest read some comparisons, for example [here](https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf).  The `\midrule` is usually better than a `\hline` because add small spaces above/after the line, increasing the readability, but this prevents connect with vertical lines, that are rare in formal tables . But if you insist on making birdcage-like tables, then just use `\hline` everywhere and do not use the `booktabs` rules.

Comment: @MathiasAndersen Or with `booktabs` you can use special rules as `\specialrule{1pt}{2pt}{0pt}` instead of `\toprule` to connect with the vertical lines.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice. The formatting you suggest looks better